# How to Wrap text in span and not breaking words?

Tags: html, text, wrapper, break, cpu-word

I have a small code that wraps text in span. The problem is that the wrap doesn't consider the white spaces to change the line and break the words in the middle.

The span text is for a function that animates letters independently, that's the reason for the inline-block.

**JS:**

```
        $('.text').html(function (i, html) {
            var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
            return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
        });
```

**CSS:**

```
    .text span {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `inline-block` is treated as its own word. To make words stick together you could wrap each word in another `span` for example like this:

```js
$('.text').each((i, e) => {
  const element = $(e);
  element.html(element.text().split(' ').map(word => {
    const letters = (word + ' ').split('').map(char => '<span>' + char + '</span>');
    return '<span class="word">' + letters.join('') + '</span>';
  }).join(''));
});
```

```css
.text .word {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or, if all you need are just spaces between letters, you can achieve it using `letter-spacing` and `word-spacing`

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in my case. The .text are titles in different parts of the page, and now all the span text is grouped together and showing in every .text location.

Comment: I assumed that you only have one `.text` element. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, now it kinda works. BUT because there's an animation for every span, the animation of the letters is multiplied by 2 because of the double span. Any workaround to this?

Comment: Instead of animating `span` animate `.word span`. Or alternatively change the tag with class `word` in my script from `span` to some other element eg `div`.